# Validate form input on keyup with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to build my form so that when a user fills in an input and presses enter they get the next input field.

I've got this working okay in the fact it shows the next div only I can't get the validation working...

```js
// Form on enter next div...
$(window).load(function(){
$('footer .active input').on("keyup", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
        if( $('footer .active input').val().length === 0 ){
            alert('NO!');
        } else {
            var $activeElement = $("footer .active");
            $( "footer .active" ).next().addClass( "active" ).removeClass('inactive');
            $activeElement.removeClass("active").addClass('inactive');
        }
    }
});
});
```

```css
form {
    overflow: hidden;
    width:100%; min-height:200px;
    position:relative;
}
div.inactive {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    width:100%;
    border-bottom:1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
}
input { 
    padding:2.5rem 0;
    font-size:4rem;
    font-weight:200;
    width:80%;
}
.active {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<footer>
    <form action="">
        <div class="input active">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Who are you?" />
        </div>
        <div class="input inactive">
            <input type="text" placeholder="What is your Email?" />
        </div>
        <div class="enter-btn"></div>
    </form>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to use `$(document).on("keyup",'footer .active input', function(e) {})`

```js
// Form on enter next div...
$(document).on("keyup", 'footer .active input', function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    if ($('footer .active input').val() == '') {
      alert('NO!');
    } else {
      var $activeElement = $("footer .active");
      $("footer .active").next().addClass("active");
      $activeElement.removeClass("active");
    }
  }
});
```

```css
form {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 200px;
  position: relative;
}
form div.input {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
}
form div.input input {
  padding: 2.5rem 0;
  font-size: 4rem;
  font-weight: 200;
  width: 80%;
}
form div.input.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<footer>
  <form action="">
    <div class="input active">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Who are you?" />
    </div>
    <div class="input">
      <input type="text" placeholder="What is your Email?" />
    </div>
    <div class="enter-btn"></div>
  </form>
</footer>
```

Comment: That's not the issue @Carsten - I have it working as in it moves to the next div, I just want to validate the input has been filled in before allowing the function to run

Comment: Sorry forgot to add the part also, changed it

Comment: Oooh I see, thanks for taking the time to respond - works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Change the line:

```
if( $('footer .active input').length === '' ){
```

to

```
if( $('footer .active input').val() == '' ){
```

and try again.

**Note:** you have to check the value entered in the input.

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g51xbfy6/4/)

Answer (score 0):

do not use "length === '' "
length returns a interger so you can't compare it to an empty string (with typeof string)
try

```
if( $('footer .active input').val().length <= 0 ){
```

Answer (score 0):

This line of code right here:

```
if( $('footer .active input').length === ''
```

This comparison is wrong for three reasons:

1. You're comparing an expected number value to a string value using a [strict comparison operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators)
2. You should expect the value of length to be `0`, not an empty string
3. You're comparing the property `length` of a jQuery object, which is equivalent to the number of DOM elements that match your selector.

Change the line to this:

```
if($('footer .active input').val().length == 0)
```

Or this, if you don't want to check the length:

```
if($('footer .active input').val() == '')
```

**Note:** you might want to use `e.target` instead of querying the same element twice.

Answer (score -2):

`$('footer .active input').length` is the number of elements that match the selector. If you want to get the input's value use `.val()` instead:

```
// Form on enter next div...
$('footer .active input').on("keyup", function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    if ($('footer .active input').val() == '') {
      alert('NO!');
    } else {
      var $activeElement = $("footer .active");
      $("footer .active").next().addClass("active");
      $activeElement.removeClass("active");
    }
  }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/g51xbfy6/2/